# Python Script using Multithreading creates memory leak

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a script that I converted to use multithreading since it did slow http requests and is way faster in parallel.
It works decent, but after a while my memory fills up. I think it is because of the second loop inside the multithreaded loop. Im pretty new to multithreading.
Can someone help me fix the memory leak?

```
from logging import Manager
import json
import threading 

tokens = []
query = 'SELECT * FROM tokens'
cur.execute(query)

def threaded_execution(row, threads, row_n):
    tokenid = str(row[0])
    contract = row[1]
    network = row[2]
    pair_data = getPairs(network, contract)
    cur2.execute("insert into pairs_history (tokenid, data, date) values (%s, %s, %s)",
             (tokenid, pair_data, time.time()))
    cnx.commit()
    for x in json.loads(pair_data):
        try:
            if(x[0][4] != "0.00" and x[0][4] != "0.0" and x[0][4] != 0.0):
                cur3.execute("insert into prices_history (tokenid,price,date,exchange) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)",(tokenid, x[0][4], time.time(), x[0][5]))
                cnx.commit()
        except:
            pass
    threads.remove(row_n)

MAX_THREADS = 3

row_n = 0
threads = []
for row in cur:
    while len(threads) > MAX_THREADS:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    t = threading.Thread(target=threaded_execution, args=(row, threads, row_n))
    threads.append(row_n)
    t.start()
    row_n += 1


while threads:
    time.sleep(0.1)

cur.close()
cur2.close()
cur3.close()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: You're storing the entire table in memory before you even begin to create threads. If the table is large it will take up a lot of memory. Try having each thread load one row and process it (according to some index for example)

Comment: Also, you're creating at most 3 threads at the same time, but each time one finishes running you're creating more and more threads to replace them without removing the previous objects from memory